# How to remove table dotted lines in Latex?

Tags: tables

When I compile this in overleaf, I am getting dotted lines in the table. If I use \hline instead of \cline, I am not able to retain the merged cells in first column. What should I do? How can I  make those dotted lines into thick lines?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
                                                    & q & w\% & e & r & t \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{asdasda} &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{asdasda}  &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{asd}                        &     &       &          &     &            \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{asdasda}                  &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \cline{2-6} 
                                                    &     &       &          &     &          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Comment: "Undefined control sequence. \multirow" Post a minimal working example.

Comment: Also, I get the desired result that you show.

Comment: Is it working in Overleaf?  I am trying and the output has dotted lines in it. The document says cline is for partial horizontal line. I am adding the link: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables

Comment: Is there a way I could get the desired table?

Comment: I also noticed that latex is working better on normal latex platform but has a problem in overleaf :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess is that the "dotted lines" problem, as you put it, arose because you were using `\cmidrule` rather than `\cline` directives. `\cmidrule` is a macro provided by the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package.

You have two options:

1. If you want to use `\cmidrule` and the other line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, do *not* use vertical lines in the table.
2. If you believe your table must employ vertical lines, do *not* use the macros of the `booktabs` package. Instead, use only `\cline` (and `\hline`).

Since your desired-output screenshot features lots and lots of vertical lines, I think you need to go with the second option.

Incidentally, it is necessary to load the [multirow](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package in order to make your code compilable.

Your desired-output screenshot further suggests that the column widths should all equal some fixed value. If that is indeed the case, I would like to suggest that you load the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package and employ its `wc` column type instead of the basic `c` column type. In the code below, I specify 2.5cm as the width of the first column and 1.25cm as the widths of the data columns. Do adjust these numbers to fit your document's needs (about which I have zero knowledge).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% \usepackage{amsxtra}   % are you SURE you need this package?
%%  \usepackage{graphicx} % nothing good ever comes from loading packages twice

% new:
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' directive
\usepackage{array}    % for 'wc' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] % why do you use 'table*' ??
\caption{Hello\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}
\centering % <-- new
\begin{tabular}{|wc{2.5cm}|*{5}{wc{1.25cm}|}}
\hline
  & q & w\% & e & r & t \\  \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{asdasda} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{asdasda}  
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{asd}    
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{asdasda}    
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's worth the OP reading the `booktabs` documentation which makes a forthright case that tables should never contain vertical lines.

Comment: @dbmag9 - Thanks. I absolutely agree with you. :-) I chose not to include your suggestion in my answer lest I come across as being needlessly preachy. That said, the OP could do a lot worse than assimilate the main message of the `booktabs` package, which is that vertical lines are neither necessary nor sufficient for creating aesthetically appealing tables. In fact, vertical lines (and an abundance of unnecessary, poorly spaced horizontal lines) quite often suffice to assure that the table's "look" is unappealing and even ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried compiling it on overleaf. The format did not change. I am not sure what is the real issue :(

Comment: @Iamnotperfect - Please clarify the meaning of "The format did not change." (Aside: My psychic or mind-reading skills are sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, worthless.)

Comment: It's my bad,  I meant it's still as the "output" but not as "desired output".

Comment: Well, I figured out what is the problem. I was trying to use this on springer nature which does not allow this format. I guess I have to do something without the verticle lines as you mentioned.  Well, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Iamnotperfect - There are several, fairly similar, LaTeX document classes generally referred to as "Springer Nature". Which particular document class do you employ?

Comment: \documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl).  This is the class I used.

Comment: @Iamnotperfect - Just out of curiosity: Why did you indicate in your test document that you the document class you employ -- a piece of information that's generally absolutely crucial -- is `article` when, in fact, you use `sn-jnl` with the option `sn-mathphys`? You could have saved yourself (and me too) lots and lots of time by revealing the document class you employ up front.

Comment: That was something I realized after multiple failures that I missed mentioning the basic component. Now all I have are regrets :(

Comment: @Iamnotperfect - Don't wallow in regrets. Mainly, view it as a learning opportunity.